# how to customize the response of a api from retrieve function in mixin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm a beginner to Django, i have written a class-based API view with mixin. the functionality is simple i.e fetch the data of the given id.Im pasting the code below.

```
class GenericAPi(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
queryset=Article.objects.all()
lookup_field="id"
def get(self,request,id):
    if id:
        data=self.retrieve(request)
        return Response({"data":data.data,"status":data.status_code})
    else:
        return self.list(request)
```

this is the response I'm getting

{"id":5,"title":"loream","author":"me"}

then I navigate to the retrieve function in the mixin, to make some changes in the response.

```
 def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('Retrieving')
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response({"result":serializer.data})
```

and then I make a call to API, but still, I'm getting the same response.
How to customize the response in the retrieve function itself.

I need response like this.

{"result":{"id":5,"title":"loream","author":"ipsum"}}

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to customize `retrieve` function in the `RetrieveModelMixin`.

```
class GenericAPi(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
    queryset=Article.objects.all()
    lookup_field="id"
    def get(self, request, id):
        if id:
            try:
                article = Article.objects.get(pk = id)
                return Response({"result": ArticleSerializer(article).data})
            except Article.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return 
            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have done that, it's only reflecting response if the data exist in DB,if case data doesn't exist the response does not return from the class we have written. i.e {"detail":"Not found."} , where does this response come from]

Comment: You mean, `id` can be not correct?

Comment: yes,in that case im getting {"detail":"Not found."}

Comment: I changed the code to return 404 if id does not exist. Please check it.

Comment: where did u change that in views or mixin.py

Comment: I didn't change anything mixin.py just add `try except`

Comment: that's working perfectly fine, is there any way to make edit to mixins.py response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245142/discussion-between-akhil-and-david-lu).